# Project compiles in IDE but not in Maven

Tags: java, maven, compiler-errors, compilation

So I have no problem in my IDE with the project, but when I run mvn clean install on command line, I get the following:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:
compile (default-compile) on project myproject: Compilation failure

[ERROR] /C:/Users/myuser/gitprojects/myprojects/src/main/java/com/path/MyClass.java:[175,131] incompatible types: 
java.util.List<com.mycompany.Class2> cannot be converted to java.util.List<com.mycompany.Class>
```

How can Maven be unable to handle those generics when IDE has no problem?

Comment: Can you post the code of `MyClass.java`?

Comment: Check the versions of maven in your IDE and in the system, if they are differents you can get strange errors.

Comment: The thing is, other user doesn't have problems building this with maven but he's currently on a holiday. So, identical codebase, no changes to those classes. maven builds it in his environment with the same command but doesn't build it on mine. Could be a  maven version thing yes.